# Can a Service Fabric Container project pull from Docker Hub?

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I have created a new Service Fabric Container project in Visual Studio that I am trying to test by publishing to the local cluster. I have created a Windows Container image that I have run locally in Docker. I pushed the image to a private registry in Docker Hub.

When I publish the project to the local cluster, it deploys, but then I get an error:

```
Error event: SourceId='System.Hosting', Property='Download:1.0:1.0'.
There was an error during download.Failed to download container image docker.io/(username)/(repository)
```

All the examples show pulling an image from Azure Container Registry. Does Service Fabric only work with ACR, or do I have to add additional configuration to my service manifest to use a private Docker Hub registry?

Edit: also, it seems unable to find the container locally. I tried using the tagged local name of the image from the local repository (I checked using "docker images" and it is there). Same result. Service Fabric should be able to find it:

> Service Fabric will pull down the image (if it's not already in the local registry) and launch a container based on the arguments you provide.

from [MSDN blog on Service Fabric](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureservicefabric/2016/04/25/orchestrating-containers-with-service-fabric/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the problem is that Service Fabric does not support container deployment on Windows 10 (and my dev machine is Win10, so local development/testing is out). There are notes to this effect on the [Azure Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-containers-overview) but I guess I didn't notice them or glossed over them...